# Why is my set up short circuiting?

Tags: capacitor, short-circuit

Disclaimer: I'm a noob.

I have the following schematic (updated as per @Transistor):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I had first tried this out on my breadboard. It worked fine. From what I read online, this was two capacitors set up in parallel.

When I do the setup on a PCB prototype board, it short circuits (I'm assuming it is a short circuit because the lights of my Arduino Uno go off.)

Is this enough information for someone to be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong? I can post a picture of what the setup actually looks like if needed.

Comment: Hi, a picture (photo) of both sides of the board might be helpful here.

Comment: It is very difficult to see, where there could be a short circuit. No offense, but I recommend to discard this board and do some soldering exercises first. It's been a while since I have seen such soldering joints. I've seen worse, but not many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't enough information in the question to answer fully but your schematic is not correct.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiCQ3H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. 5 V supply, decoupling capacitors and servo connection.*

If you can clarify in your question what is going on we will help further.

[image]

*Figure 2. The short-circuit.*

Comment: What kind of info so you need? When I complete the circuit, the LED lights of my Arduino go off. The servo doesn't turn on.

Comment: @Yousuf, I'm probably many thousands of kilometers away from you so I can't see what you have done wrong. Don't you think a photo would help? Add one or more into your question using the edit link below it.

Comment: Can you have a look now? I know the soldering is terrible, but i'm still working on developing my skills.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Oh shoot, i didnt realize that. Let me try to remove that and i'll accept your answer if it works.

Comment: YES! It worked!

Answer (score 4):

Both the 5v and the GND are connected to the same pin of the capacitor. Since there is no resistance in this path, your circuit ends up shorting to ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flIByl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've redrawn your circuit with more legibility here.

Comment: Actually, it's not like that. I have the 5v to the positive side and the ground to the negative side of the capacitors.

Comment: @Yousuf That's how your initial schematic was. I answered the question before you updated the schematic.